# gethostbyname works fine in fedora 32 bit but fails on 64 bit

Tags: c, linux, sockets

`gethostbyname` works fine in fedora 32 bit but is failing on 64 bit environment giving a segmentation fault? In such scenario what is the problem and how can we resolve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <netdb.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>  

struct hostent *he;  
struct in_addr a; 

int main (int argc, char **argv)  {  

    if (argc != 2)  {  
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s hostname\n", argv[0]);  
        return 1;  
    }  

    he = gethostbyname (argv[1]);  
    if (he)  {  
        printf("name :- %s\n", he->h_name);  
        while (*he->h_aliases)  
            printf("alias:- %s\n", *he->h_aliases++);  
        while (*he->h_addr_list)  {  
            bcopy(*he->h_addr_list++, (char *) &a, sizeof(a));  
            printf("address:- %s\n", inet_ntoa(a));  
        }  
    }  
    else  
        herror(argv[0]);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: That means you made a mistake somewhere in your code.

Comment: Most likely, the name you provide to `gethostbyname` is corrupt. Maybe you've stored it in an integer and lost the high bits. Anyway, the problem is in your code, not `gethostbyname`.

Comment: impossible to help you by guessing ... you probably want to post some code.

Comment: edit your question with some code...

Comment: Next time please make sure you properly format your code. I [have done so for you now](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11561447/revisions). Have a look at the differences.

Comment: Run your code through gdb and post a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the correct includes:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Without the correct includes, `inet_ntoa` is assumed to have a return type of `int`. Because `int` has the same size as `char*` on x86, there is no problem. This is not true on x86_64, so the read of that string by `printf` causes a fault.

Comment: And that error would have being caught by the warnings given by `gcc -Wall -Wextra`, so if you care about all warnings given by the compiler, you would not have it.

Comment: Yeah, it's worth mentioning that in C, “warning” means “error unless you know better” and one usually doesn't.